# discord\cog.py:672: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'setup' was never awaited setup(self)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im attemping to use cogs to split my commands up and keep my code organized, However im struglging at figuring out why this code does not work for me, Personally i cant find where the await function would fit in?

Main.py Code

```
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is Online!")
    change_status.start()
    bot.load_extension("cogs.help")


Cogs Code:


class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
        await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")
        

async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Comment: regarding the last line of code, I have tried having await bot.add_cog(Test(bot)) But there seems to be no difference in the error im getting currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html) may be of interest to you. It explains how to migrate from V1 of discordpy to V2. Indeed, since V2, the `add_cog` function is asynchronous, so you have to define your `setup` function asynchronously too. The same goes for the `load_extension` function which has become asynchronous.

```py
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is Online!")
    change_status.start()
    await bot.load_extension("cogs.help")


Cogs Code:


class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
        await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")
        

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to await the add_cog to make it work properly.

You have to edit the add_cog in setup you can do this like this:-

```
await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `bot` as `bot: commands.Bot` at `def __init__(self, bot):` and `async def setup(bot):`.

`commands.Bot` is what represents a Discord bot, `bot` is a parameter you need to set.

You also have to await `bot.add_cog()`, as mentioned by others.

Full code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):

def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
    self.bot = bot

    
@commands.command()
async def hello(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.name}")
    

async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```